# Pushforward of a maximal Cohen-Macaulay sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay-rings

Let $X$ be an (affine) noetherian, Cohen-Macaulay scheme of dimension at least $2$. Choose a closed point $x \in X$. Denote by $U:=X\setminus \{x\}$ the open subset and $i:U \to X$ the natural inclusion. Let $F$ be a maximal Cohen-Macaulay sheaf over $U$. Is the direct image $i_*F$ a maximal Cohen-Macaulay sheaf over $X$? If necessary, assume that $U$ is non-singular. The question has positive answer in the case the dimension of $X$ is $2$.

Comment: This is false in general for $\dim>2$ even for regular rings. Take the first syzygy of the ideal defining $x$, restricted to $U$.